# Order categories by name or view count

Tags: categories, order

I have a piece of code in witch i cant figure out how to order my subcategories by names or by view count. I have tried a lot of thing but my coding skills ate not good enough. This code displays subcategories of my two parent categories. I would be thankful if you helped me to order them by name or view count.

Thanks!

```
<?php $terms = array();
$taxonomy = 'category';
$parents = array(32, 36);
foreach ($parents as $parent) {
    $terms = array_merge($terms, get_categories(array('child_of'=> $parent)));
}

foreach ($terms as $cat) : ?>


    <?php endforeach; ?>
```